# LinearLayout layout:width="match_parent" and layout:height="match_parent" keeps changing to a fixed dp

Tags: android, android-layout

Every time I change the value to `match_parent`, it changes to the preview screen size in a fixed `dp`. This does not work because when testing on a tablet vs a phone, the layout does not work out at all. When I turn off the preview it does stop doing it and everything still works fine, the second I turn on the preview and hover over it, it changes to a fixed dp.

Is there any way I can turn this off?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Team A"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+3 Points"/>

      <Button

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+2 Points"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Free Throw"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.remove this in your code .

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
```

If you set `tools` in the layout . It will preview in the xml layout .

2.set the `android:orientation="vertical"` in your code .

Comment: Removing the code tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" just makes the layout stack on top of each other and i want the preview to stay, it is set to vertical,  i want to know if there's a way to turn it off where it automaticlly changes?

Answer (score 0):

## Try To implement like that

- `remove parent Constraint layout` i think your are using `Constaints`
- you have to implement like that `instead` of what you doing
- just `remove these lines`
  `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"`

`tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"`

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Team A"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+3 Points"/>

<Button

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+2 Points"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Free Throw"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

---

- Here's your `xml` **OUTPUT**

---

[image]

Comment: Yes this works when executing, but my question is is there a setting to turn off that thing where it automatically changes to a fixed dp value? if yes, please tell me how to get there